# Link with onclick event is not working after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I created a Facebook game that contains some XML code.

In the game over screen, I want to add a Facebook share message that automatically captures the score from the game.

I was able to get it to work with the following code just fine:

```
a(".gameover_bg").append('<p>Congrats!</p><p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=THIS IS MY TITLE&p[summary]=THIS IS YOUR SCORE: '+ u +'&p[url]=http://www.MYURL.com&&p[images][0]=http://www.MYURL.com/img/IMAGEADDRESS" target="_blank">SHARE THIS NOW</a></p>')
```

But I would like to add a javascript onclick event so that the link opens in a specific size window of 555 width and 315 height. When I change the code from above to the one below, it's no longer working for me. I think it has to do with the the quotes somewhere...

```
a(".gameover_bg").append('<p>Congrats!</p><p><a class="share" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=THIS IS MY TITLE&p[summary]=THIS IS YOUR SCORE: '+ u +'&p[url]=http://www.MYURL.com&&p[images][0]=http://www.MYURL.com/img/IMAGEADDRESS', 'newwindow', 'width=555, height=315'); return false;">SHARE THIS NOW</a></p>')
```

I'm including an image that maybe will illustrate better how I'm writing this:
[image: code]

Would appreciate any advice on how to make the second code above valid (just like the first one works).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you aren't escaping your quotation marks? Try replacing the ' with a \' inside the window.open call

Comment: You cant escape things in a single quote ('), but you can escape in a double quote (").

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

This seemed to take care of the trick:

```
a(".gameover_bg").append("<p>Congrats!</p><p><a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=THIS IS MY TITLE&p[summary]=THIS IS MY SUMMARY: "+ u +"&p[url]=http://www.MYURL.com&&p[images][0]=http://www.MYURL.com/img/IMAGEADDRESS' onclick='window.open(this.href, &quot;newwindow&quot;, &quot;width=555, height=315&quot;); return false;'>SHARE THIS NOW!</a></p>")
```

Comment: It's because you cant escape things in a single quote ('), but you can escape in a double quote (") - and also, single quotes do not need to be escaped within double quotes.